# Non-singular conics

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm struggling to understand what a non-singular conic is. Google isn't helping and neither are my lecture notes. Is anyone able to give me a quick definition or example of one?
A past paper has the following question:
Decide whether or not the following quadratic form defines a non-singular conic;
x^2-2xy+4xz-8y^2+2yz+3z^2.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: My google [is helping](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~john/geometry/Lectures/L24.html).

Comment: $(x+2y+z)(x-4y+3z)=0$